# How to autofill NULL values when using SPLIT formula in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I'm trying to figure out how I would go about using the `SPLIT` function in Big Query SQL while filling in the `NULL` values that associate with when using the `SPLIT` function. For this example I have two columns in my table currently and looks like this:

```
    Name             |           Price
 Jake                |       19.99,20.00,21.00
 Jane                |       15.00,13.99,14.00
 Joe                 |       17.99,12.00,15.00,17.99
 John                |       18.00,10.00
```

The output I'm getting currently when I do, `SPLIT(Price, ',') AS Price_Split` is the following:

```
    Name             |           Price
 Jake                |       19.99
                     |       20.00
                     |       21.00
 Jane                |       15.00
                     |       13.99
                     |       14.00
 Joe                 |       17.99
                     |       12.00
                     |       15.00
                     |       17.99
 John                |       18.00
                     |       10.00
```

What I'm trying to make my end result look like is:

```
    Name             |           Price
 Jake                |       19.99
 Jake                |       20.00
 Jake                |       21.00
 Jane                |       15.00
 Jane                |       13.99
 Jane                |       14.00
 Joe                 |       17.99
 Joe                 |       12.00
 Joe                 |       15.00
 Joe                 |       17.99
 John                |       18.00
 John                |       10.00
```

How would I go about auto filling in the Names that correspond correctly? Or should I go about this a different way/different formula? Any help with this would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Please show us your existing query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `UNNEST`

```
WITH data AS(
  SELECT 'Joe' as name, SPLIT('17.99,12.00,15.00,17.99', ',') AS r 
)
SELECT
name,r
FROM data,
UNNEST(r) r


"name","r"
"Joe","17.99"
"Joe","12.00"
"Joe","15.00"
"Joe","17.99"
```

Comment: For OP, `SPLIT()` returns an array.  Unnesting will then populate the name field for each unnested value.  Also, the "NULLs" you see are not actually nulls, they are each a single record associated with the nested array.

Comment: This did it perfectly! Thank you so much, really appreciate it!